# Merge JSON objects through unique field then print child node data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following JSON:

```
data: {
    questions: "[{"id":"vzDDWL3GQvJi","title":"This is question 1","type":"opinion_scale","ref":"data_q1","properties":[]},{"id":"okT0ieWJm74d","title":"This  is question 2","type":"opinion_scale","ref":"data_q2","properties":[]},

    answers: "[{"type":"number","number":2,"field":{"id":"vzDDWL3GQvJi","type":"opinion_scale","ref":"data_q1"}},{"type":"number","number":4,"field":{"id":"okT0ieWJm74d","type":"opinion_scale","ref":"data_q2"}},

    createdDate: "2020-02-14T07:43:02.000000Z"
}
```

A tidy version of the above is:

**Question** (`questions` object)

- **title** : "This is question 1"
- **ref**" : "data_q1"

**Answer** (`answers` object)

- **ref**" : "data_q1"
- **number** : 2

So, for question 1 (with the ref: `data_q1`) the number (score) is 2.

What I'm trying to do, is to merge both questions answers together based on `ref`. I want to do this so that I can get the `number`. I.e. question and answer for `data_q1` is 2.

I have the following:

```
// Get questions
var questionData = data.data.questions;
var questions = JSON.parse(questionData);

// get answers
var answerData = data.data.answers;
var answers = JSON.parse(answerData);
```

What I've tried:

```
var answersInfo = answers.map( function(order) {
if( answers.ref === "RefIDHere"){
     var info = { "number": answers.number}
     return info;
 }
});
console.log(answersInfo);
```

However, the issue with the above is, in `answers.ref ===`, I don't know what to pass because the questions and answers haven't been mapped together yet.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @goto1 - I have updated my question  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below solution.

```
finalResult = [];
questions.map( que => 
  answers.map(ans =>  {
    if(que.ref === ans.field.ref){
      finalResult.push({question: que, answer: ans})
} 
return finalResult; 
}));
```

Now if you see finalResult has the question and respective answer and you can access the number.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! the array is looking fine. How do I get the `number` value as a variable? I've tried: `var answerScore = finalResult.answer; var aScore = JSON.parse(finalResult.answer); var aFinalScore = aScore[1];`. No luck (throws error)

Comment: Freddy , you can do something like finalResult[0].answer.number . This is for only first array element . You can loop through the finalResults array and get all the number values.

Answer (score 0):

1) Build an answer_number object which has ref as key and value as number from `data.answers`.

2) Use `map` over `data.questions` and add the number value from above.
Hope this helps.

```js
const data = {
  questions: [
    {
      id: "vzDDWL3GQvJi",
      title: "This is question 1",
      type: "opinion_scale",
      ref: "data_q1",
      properties: []
    },
    {
      id: "okT0ieWJm74d",
      title: "This  is question 2",
      type: "opinion_scale",
      ref: "data_q2",
      properties: []
    }
  ],
  answers: [
    {
      type: "number",
      number: 2,
      field: { id: "vzDDWL3GQvJi", type: "opinion_scale", ref: "data_q1" }
    },
    {
      type: "number",
      number: 4,
      field: { id: "okT0ieWJm74d", type: "opinion_scale", ref: "data_q2" }
    }
  ],
  createdDate: "2020-02-14T07:43:02.000000Z"
};

const answers_number = data.answers.reduce(
  (acc, curr) => Object.assign(acc, { [curr.field.ref]: curr.number }),
  {}
);

const questions_count = data.questions.map(que => ({
  ...que,
  number: answers_number[que.ref]
}));

console.log(questions_count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
let data = {
    questions: '[{"id":"vzDDWL3GQvJi","title":"This is question 1","type":"opinion_scale","ref":"data_q1","properties":[]},{"id":"okT0ieWJm74d","title":"This  is question 2","type":"opinion_scale","ref":"data_q2","properties":[]}]',
    answers: '[{"type":"number","number":2,"field":{"id":"vzDDWL3GQvJi","type":"opinion_scale","ref":"data_q1"}},{"type":"number","number":4,"field":{"id":"okT0ieWJm74d","type":"opinion_scale","ref":"data_q2"}}]',
    createdDate: "2020-02-14T07:43:02.000000Z"
}

let getQuestionAndAnswer = (data, ref) => {
  let question = JSON.parse(data.questions).filter(v => v.ref === ref);
  let answer = JSON.parse(data.answers).filter(v => v.field.ref === ref);
  
  return {
      question,
      answer
    };
};

console.log(getQuestionAndAnswer(data, "data_q1"));
```